# For the inline enumerate: controlling the item spacing

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemsep = 1.125in, label=(\Alph*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{choices}
\item Test
\item Test
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

In this case, the `itemsep` is meant to control the **horizontal spacing** between `\item`s.

The `itemsep` is not functioning correctly; is there another way to do what I'm looking for? I've tried `listparindent` and `labelsep` already.

Comment: Please complete your code so that you provide a minimal example which we can use to reproduce the error. On the way, you will discover the answer to part of your question for yourself (i.e. whether it is due to a package you haven't mentioned). It will be much easier for people to help when you have provided enough information.

Comment: @cfr - MWE coming up.

Comment: Try `itemjoin = {\hskip 1.125in}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is `itemjoin`. Here the distance between the items can be controlled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hspace{1.125in}, label=(\Alph*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{choices}
\item Test
\item Test
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

[image]