# How to calculate the width of a space?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem, calculations, lengths

Using the questions:

1. [Get width of a given text as length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length)
2. [Lengths and when to use them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them)
3. [enumitem package and description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56249/enumitem-package-and-description-lists)
4. [For the inline enumerate: controlling the item spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211097/for-the-inline-enumerate-controlling-the-item-spacin)
5. [Customizing inline enumerate with enumitem still not working?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/customizing-inline-enumerate-with-enumitem-still-not-working)

I am trying to set my inline list inter space to one space `\` using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist*[inlinelist,1]{label=}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

some text \begin{inlinelist}[label=,itemjoin=\the\widthof{\ }]
    \item First Keyword.
    \item Second Keyword.
    \item Third Keyword.
\end{inlinelist} more text

\end{document}
```

But it is not setting the correct size and it is showing some stranger text:

[image]

How can I properly calculate the size of a space `\` and set the `itemjoin` to this value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist*[inlinelist,1]{label=}
\newlength{\interwordspace}
\settowidth{\interwordspace}{\ }

\begin{document}

some text \begin{inlinelist}[label=,itemjoin=\hspace{\interwordspace}]
    \item First Keyword.
    \item Second Keyword.
    \item Third Keyword.
\end{inlinelist} more text

some text \begin{inlinelist}[label=,itemjoin=\hspace{\fontdimen2\font}]
    \item First Keyword.
    \item Second Keyword.
    \item Third Keyword.
\end{inlinelist} more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note that `\widthof` can only be used in the context of setting lengths and some other few cases, but not after `\the` (but `\the` would be misused, in this application, because it only produces *strings of characters*, see [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38674/the-the-command)).

What about `itemjoin={ }`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist*[inlinelist,1]{label=}

\begin{document}

some text\begin{inlinelist}[,itemjoin={ }]
\item First Keyword
\item Second Keyword
\item Third Keyword
\end{inlinelist}
more text

some text First Keyword Second Keyword Third Keyword more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was what I wanted when I looked into setting the item join space to a space.  Somehow using the space width was doubling it.